# Aggregate by date sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, group-by

i have a table with columns:

```
ID_LOG (this is the pk) | TS (type=datetime) | VALUE (type=double) | ID_CHANNEL (unique).
```

This table logs values form different channels every 15 minutes. The values are taken from some counters so they are always increasing.
Now i want to get the differences between maximum value and minimum value (so the net difference) of every day of last year of a specific channel.
Something like:

```
SELECT MAX(T1.value) - MIN(T1.value), T1.ts
FROM dbo.[LOG] as T1
WHERE T1.ts > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) and
T1.ID_CHANNEL=x      //[x being the channel i want]
GROUP BY SOMEDATEFUNCITON(T1.ts) //[SOMEDATEFUNCTION is the function that groups results by date not taking in consideration the time of timestamp but only year-month-day]
```

I don't care about efficency as i will do this query only once or twice per year.
Is this possible? And how you'd do?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT convert(char(10), creationDate, 120), COUNT(custID) AS totalRegistered
FROM dbo.SecureSignInUser
WHERE (CreationDate BETWEEN '11/1/2004' AND '11/30/2004'
```

GROUP BY `convert(char(10), creationDate, 120)`

check this for your date format ..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

cast/ convert your function return date value format according to your database date format.

Comment: This actually did the trick even on sql server 2005. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CAST(T1.ts AS DATE)` to truncate the timestamp. Substituting in to what you have:

```
SELECT MAX(T1.valore) - MIN(T1.valore), CAST(T1.ts AS DATE)
...
GROUP BY CAST(T1.ts AS DATE)
```

<sub>Although according to your schema, `TS` is already `DATE`, so you shouldn't need to do this. Did you mean to tell us that `TS` is a `DATETIME`?</sub>

Comment: yes of course it is datetime, i edited the question... sorry!

Comment: Your query gives me these errors: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type DATE is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type DATE is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: After further investigating it turns out that that server is running sql server 2005 and not 2008, so i cannot use the type data... Is there something i could do?